# my component is not reloading when state is changed is there any solution

Tags: reactjs

my component is not reloading when the state is changed is there any solution
how do I solve this problem

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import './treeNavBar.css'
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'

const TreeNavBar=(props)=>{
    const [workspaceData,changeWorkspaceData]=useState(null)
    const [reload,changeReload]=useState(false)
    let listWorkspaceData=null
    const workspace=localStorage.getItem('workspaceData')
      if(workspaceData!== workspace){
        changeWorkspaceData(workspace)
        changeReload(true)
      }
      if(workspaceData){
          listWorkspaceData=<ul  className='workspaceData ml-2'>{
          JSON.parse(workspaceData).map(data=>(
              <li key={data.id}>
                <NavLink to ={`/myworkspaceCollections/${data.id}/${data.itemCount}/${data.collectionCount}`}>
                  {data.name}
                </NavLink>
              </li>
          )
          )}</ul>
      }
    return(
        <div className='treeNavBar ml-3 '>
            <ul>
                <li><NavLink to ='/myworkspace'>My Workspaces </NavLink></li>
                {listWorkspaceData}
            </ul>
        
      )
}

export default TreeNavBar
```

my component is not reloading when the state is changed is there any solution
how do I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Route`s path. It is hard to tell what is the problem with what you share. It could be anything. Maybe your `Link` and your `Route` is not matching.